# Derivative Of Integral Vs Integral of Derivative.

Tags: measure-theory, functions, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

let $f:\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

If $f_t(.,t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(.,t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then, By *Measure Theory*:

$\frac{d}{dt}$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}$$f(x,t) dx$=$\int_{\mathbb{R}}$$f_t(x,t) dx$

But I can't understand why is this *simply* true when $f$ is a **regular function**? And in sense of what is this regularity?

Some help please?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP clarified, in the comments below,  that by **regular function** it is meant **smoth function** that is $C^k$-functions ($k\geqslant 1$).

So, for all $t$, there is $\varepsilon>0$ and  there is a function $g$ such that, for all $u \in [t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon] $,
$$|f_t(\cdot,u)| \leqslant g(\cdot) \tag{1}$$
**Let us assume that $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$**.

Let $\{h_n\}_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}h_n = 0$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t) dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{h_n} \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t+h_n) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t) dx\right) = \\
& =  \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx 
\end{align*}

Let $g_n = \frac{f(\cdot,t+h_n)  - f(\cdot,t) }{h_n}$. Then $g_n \to f_t(.,t)$  pointwise.

On the other hand, from $(1)$, we have that for all $t$, there is $\varepsilon>0$ and  $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that, for all $u \in (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon) $,
$|f_t(\cdot,u)| \leqslant g(\cdot) $. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}h_n = 0$, we have that there is $N$ such that, for all $n>N$, we have  $ [t, t+h_n] \subseteq (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon)$ and so, using Mean Value Theorem, we have, for all $x$,
$$|g_n(x)|=\left |\frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n} \right|\leqslant\sup_{u\in[t, t+h_n]}|f_t(x,u)|\leqslant g(x)$$
Now, we can apply the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem and we get

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx =  \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_t(x,t) dx$$

So we have:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t) dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{h_n} \left ( \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t+h_n) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t) dx\right) = \\
& =  \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx =\\
&  =   \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx = \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_t(x,t) dx  \tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Important Remark**: We could be tempted to answer the question by just directly writing $(2)$. The issue is that the step
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx=   \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x,t+h_n)  - f(x,t) }{h_n}dx $$
**need not be true**. In other words,  **although $g_n(\cdot) \in L^1(X)$ , $f_t(\cdot,t) \in L^1(X)$ and $g_n(\cdot) \to f_t(\cdot,t)$ pointwise**, we still have that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}}g_n(x)dx=   \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f_t(x,t)dx $$
**need not be true**.

To prove this step correctly, we need either Lebesgue Dominated Converge Theorem or Fatou's Lemma for $\limsup$. Both require that the sequence $\{|g_n|\}_n$ be dominated by a function in $L^1(\Bbb R)$. Here is exactly the point where we need $(1)$.

**Remark 2** There is another way, using Fubini, to prove that, for smooth functions
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,t) dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_t(x,t) dx$$
But then we need to add the condition that
$$ \int_{[t,t+\varepsilon]} \int_{\Bbb R} |f_t(x,t)| \; dx \; dt < \infty $$

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand why if $f$ is regular, then: **for all $t$, there is $\varepsilon>0$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that, for all $u \in (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon) $, $$|f_t(\cdot,u)| \leqslant g(\cdot) \tag{1}$$**?

Comment: And why if **$g_n \to f_t(.,t)$ pointwise, then: Using $(1)$, we have that there is $N$ such that, for all $n>N$, we have $ [t, t+h_n] \subseteq (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon)$**. How did we put $ [t, t+h_n] \subseteq (t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon)$, and how is it related to $sup_{u\in[t, t+h_n]}|f_t(x,u)|$?

Comment: Can you please answer my first comment? Cz I didnt understand it, and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sara , What is the definition of **regular function** that you are using ? There is more that possible meaning of regular function, but  typically for a  "regular" function we impose that derivative is some how limited.  I can give you a more precise answer if you tell me which definition of regular function are you using.

Comment: @Sara , there is no **then** between **pointwise** and **Using $(1)$,...**.   In fact **Using $(1)$,...** is the begining of another paragraph. I will add some words to the answer to give more details.

Comment: Concerning regular functions, I think its definition (to me) is related to smooth functions, so **A function is regular iff it's smooth, i.e $C^k$ enough, with $k \ge 0$**. Is this false? Because of that I felt somehow surprised by your above definition of regularity.

Comment: @Sara What I wrote is "typically for a 'regular' function we impose that derivative is somehow limited".  In fact, if the function is $C^k$ with $k\geqslant 1$ (not $0$), we have that the the derivative is limited. It is not usual to use the term *regular function* to mean *smooth function*. Moreover, $C^0$ functions (continuous functions) are not, in general, considered *smooth*.

Comment: @sara I have added several details to the answer. Take a look. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped. I will upvote and accept your answer for sure.

Answer (score 1):

For any $h\gt 0$, $\frac{1}{h}(\int_Rf(x,t+h)dx-\int_Rf(x,t)dx)=\int_R\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(t,x)}{h}dx$  Take the limits as $h\to 0$ and get the desired equation.

$L_1$ is needed to insure limits exist.